# How to set CommandTimeout or ConnectionTimeout in NetTiers ?

Tags: .nettiers

Does anyone know how to set the ConnectionTimeout and/or CommandTimeout in NetTiers as I have a long running query that is timing out.  I expect the query to be long running, its not a performance problem as such, I just need to know if anyone knows how to set this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the Web.config for the generated site. Its the defaultCommandTimeout provider in the Provider setting.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check that out and get back to you.
If I knew how to put a bounty on this question - i might do that too !!

Comment: Your answer is correct, so thanks, however, nettiers doesn't seem to always follow the command, ONCE it did, other times it didn't, but thanks, I was able to find  more references on the web based on your answer.

Comment: @MikeD It would be interesting if you could tell us what else you found.

Comment: so long ago, I can't remember now !

Comment: Custom stored procedures ignore this setting btw. http://nettiers.net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#I_set_the_codeNetTiersProviderDefaultCommandTimeoutcode_property_so_why_does_my_slow_Sproc_time_out_using_the_SQL_provider_8